# Updating jQuery timepicker minTime at runtime dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I am trying to update minTime of jquery time picker dynamically when I put meantime while page loading it works but when I do the same thing when user select start time it should update minTime of end time

here is my attempt to update minTime,

```
$('#datetimepicker5').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    change: tmTotalHrsOnSite
     //  minTime: '15:00'
});
$('#datetimepicker4').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    change: tmTotalHrsOnSite
     //  minTime: '15:00'
});


function tmTotalHrsOnSite () {

var picktime = jQuery('#datetimepicker4').val();

    alert(picktime);
jQuery('#datetimepicker5').timepicker({
      minTime: picktime
});
};
```

I am able to detect time on change and also getting inside the function but not being successful to update minTime to disable users to see the previous time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that worked for me is adding minTime option in onChange event, and passing time value in format specified in timePicker.

```
    $('.startTP').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm p',
            startTime: '07:00',
            interval: 5,
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            change: function (time) {
                var time = $(this).val();
                var picker = $(".endTP");
                picker.timepicker('option', 'minTime', time);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

> on change event of datepicker set your desired min time

```
 $('#dateFrom, #dateTo').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        change: function(){
    if ($(this.element).is("#dateFrom")) 
        {
            $("#dateTo").timepicker('option',{'minTime': new Date()});
        }
         else 
         {
            $("#dateFrom").timepicker('option',{'maxTime': new Date()});
         }

         //  minTime: '15:00'
    });
```

Comment: please support the answer @Kamran Hassan

Comment: Please accept answer if its suites you @Kamran Hassan